# How to set default system font in CentOS?

Tags: centos, fonts, desktop-environment, fontconfig

I want to change system font used by applications globally (or per user) in CentOS. How to do that? Perhaps I should modify `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` file? I would like to set Tahoma font for applications like it was in WinXP.

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Gnome?

Comment: No desktop, just X11 via console.

Comment: Can you give some example applications you want to change to font in? Usually the way I would suggest is to change the GTK and Qt themes.

Comment: For example - NetBeans. I can set the font of NetBeans text editor, output window, etc., but not L&F font - the system font.

Comment: NetBeans uses Java Swing. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021949/change-default-font-in-netbeans#12206143

Comment: By L&F, do you need the window title? That would usually depend on which window manager you're using.

Comment: No no, I want to change font on title bars, menus, etc... It should be OS related.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution - inserted lines below to file `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`:

```
    <!-- Fallback fonts preference order -->
    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Tahoma</family>
            <family>Arial</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Times New Roman</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>
    <alias>
        <family>monospace</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Courier New</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>


  <match target="font">
      <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
          <bool>false</bool>
      </edit>
      <edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
          <bool>true</bool>
      </edit>
      <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
          <bool>false</bool>
      </edit>
      <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
          <const>hintfull</const>
      </edit>
  </match>
```

Then updated font cache with `fc-cache`. Now desired fonts available system wide.